# JQuery ajax not send js array

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My Array in console log

```
[Id: Array[24], sort: Array[24]]
Id: Array[24]
1: "2"
2: "6"
3: "8"
4: "9"
5: "10"
6: "12"
7: "13"
8: "14"
9: "15"
10: "16"
11: "17"
12: "18"
13: "19"
14: "20"
15: "22"
16: "23"
17: "24"
18: "25"
19: "26"
20: "27"
21: "28"
22: "29"
23: "30"
length: 24
__proto__: Array[0]
length: 0
sort: Array[24]
__proto__: Array[0]
```

But ajax send dont send it

```
console.log(sortedData);
$.ajax({
    'url':$('#base_url').val() + '/admin/admin/saveSorting',
    'type':'post',
    'data': {'sortedData':sortedData},
    success:function() {
    //
    }
});
```

I try to add content type application json and Json stringfy, but it doesnt help. How can i solve this problem
Thanks for help.

Comment: That should work, assuming the page at `$('#base_url').val() + '/admin/admin/saveSorting'` accepts the data properly.

Comment: I open my network in browser, request send, but without data, when i change sortedData array to 132, or [1,2,3,4,5] for example it works fine.

Comment: `[Id: Array[24], sort: Array[24]]` that doesn't look right... arrays in javascript shouldn't have named keys. How are you creating this structure?

Comment: sortedData = [];  sortedData .Id = []; sortedData.sort = []

Comment: `sortedData = []` should be `sortedData = {}`

Comment: I agree with @KevinB , but I think you can use .serializeArray() function as well to obtain needed result. https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/